# Since Preview does not support embedded JS, am I safe from attacks using it as a vector?

Tags: security, pdf, preview

Recently, I have been doing some research on PDF attacks. From what I could gather, there are two types of attacks that seem most common: Hyperlink based and JavaScript based.

Now, flattening a PDF also strips away hyperlinks, so no problem there, but removing embedded JS is more difficult; especially for the average user. However, since Preview does not seem to support embedded JS anyway, it shouldn't be a problem, right?

Is there some other backdoor I am failing to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You're safe...

If you use Preview, you are essentially safe from *embedded* JavaScript.  This doesn't however, protect you from embedded **links** that take you to a web page with malicious code (flattening is good to strip out the link, but a user could copy/paste the link manually).

For many years, (on Windows) we have been turning off JavaScript on Adobe Reader/Acrobat because Adobe allowed the embedding of all kinds of nonsense (including Flash!) into PDF documents.  We had a system policy (applied to Active Directory attached nodes) that disabled it in the Windows registry. Apple users didn't use Adobe Acrobat or Reader so it wasn't an issue for us back then.

- The 2009 article [Protect Yourself from Adobe Acrobat and Reader Vulnerabilities](https://tidbits.com/2009/10/16/protect-yourself-from-adobe-acrobat-and-reader-vulnerabilities/) goes into detail about the vulnerability and how Preview isn't susceptible
- The ***Adobe*** knowledge base article updated March of 2023, [JavaScripts in PDFs as a security risk](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/javascripts-pdfs-security-risk.html) shows it's still an ongoing issue.

(IMO) they could have included a very limited subset of JavaScript for actions like input validation in forms and whatnot, but no...

#### TL;DR

You're safe.  Continue using Preview for opening PDFs as Apple's decision to not include support is an excellent safety mechanism to protect against malicious code, but still be vigilant against embedded URLs that can take your browser to sites with malicious code.

If you must use Adobe Reader or Acrobat (for creating), then be certain to disable JavaScript in it's Preferences/Settings pane.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer, it was also very interesting to know where the decision came from.

Comment: I haven't thought about this vulnerability in years - thanks for giving me the impetus to get an update on its status (sadly, nothing's changed!)